# Recovering non-synched iCloud notes

Tags: macos, icloud, notes.app

I created a few notes on my MacBook in iCloud folder. When I realized that the notes weren't synching, I turned off and on notes in Settings → iCloud.

My new notes are lost (they are not present in icloud.com).
My old notes are still not showing up.

How can I go about recovering new notes as well as synching old ones?

Comment: At risk of sounding pedantic, when you say "a few notes on my Macbook", are you referring to the `Notes` app, or to generic notes you may have (for example) created in `TextEdit`? Also, when you say "I turned off and on notes in Settings->iCloud", do you mean the "check-box"  for the `Notes` app in `System Preferences, iCloud`? You should also [read this, as it may answer your question](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT207689)

Comment: i refer to Notes app. I first unchecked Notes box in iCloud. When it did not work, i logged out of iCloud completely.

Comment: I think what happened to you is covered in the link from my previous comment.